# Error installing python pandas in aws instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pandas

Hi I've created an aws instance and I want to run a python code in it but I have problems installing the packages.

I did a `pip install pandas` and this was the error shown:

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_ubuntu/pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I admit I'm guilty of this too, but next time read the error log, it says to install python-dev.

Comment: The error I was getting: `greenlet.h:8:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`